# How to add specific class to specific id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im try to add specific class when the user click the li with specific id, im try to do when the li has click remove all of the other class previously and add a specific class to this li, for exemple if the user click in li with id 1 the class asigned is one, if the user click in li with id 2 the class add is two and remove the previously class one etc, etc. My code look like this:

```
<ul class="menu-primary">

    <li id="1"><a href="#">Index</a></li>
    <li id="2" ><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    <li id="3"><a  href="#">Thats why</a></li>
    <li id="4"><a id="3" href="#">Sports</a></li>
    <li id="5"><a id="4" href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li id="6"><a id="5" href="#">Things about history</a></li>
    <li id="7"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

jquery look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('.menu-primary #1').hasClass('one')){
   $('.menu-primary #1').removeClass('one')
}else{
  $('.menu-primary #1').addClass('one')
}

if($('.menu-primary #2').hasClass('dos')){
   $('.menu-primary #2').removeClass('dos')
}else{
  $('.menu-primary #2').addClass('dos')
}

if($('.menu-primary #3').hasClass('three')){
   $('.menu-primary #3').removeClass('three')
}else{
  $('.menu-primary #3').addClass('three')
}

if($('.menu-primary #4').hasClass('four')){
   $('.menu-primary #4').removeClass('four')
}else{
  $('.menu-primary #4').addClass('four')
}

if($('.menu-primary #5').hasClass('five')){
   $('.menu-primary #5').removeClass('five')
}else{
  $('.menu-primary #5').addClass('five')
}

if($('.menu-primary #6').hasClass('six')){
   $('.menu-primary #6').removeClass('six')
}else{
  $('.menu-primary #6').addClass('six')
}

if($('.menu-primary #7').hasClass('seven')){
   $('.menu-primary #7').removeClass('seven')
}else{
  $('.menu-primary #7').addClass('seven')
}

});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you be more clear? where's your click event?

Comment: i dont add that but almost i added the click event, the code doesnt do anithing, but my answer is resolved i dont considered add the atrr id.

Comment: Check out a perfectly engineered code below. Using attribute sounds like a kind of school boy logic. Isn't it? And also stackoverflow provides you permission to change your acceptance at any moment. I think you got what i mean.

Comment: Probably but for a principiant like me the if statments is a great way to resolve things im no enginner o programmer Just a designer and this time im learning js and the Best way to do is learn the básicos and if is Just the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add handler on li, after i remove attribute Class from li and add new class

```
$('.menu-primary li').click(function(){
       $('.menu-primary li').removeAttr("class");
       if($(this).attr("id")=="1"){
          $(this).addClass("one");
       }
       if($(this).attr("id")=="2"){
          $(this).addClass("two");
       }
       if($(this).attr("id")=="3"){
          $(this).addClass("three");
       }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lTasty/kLm1fb0v/

Comment: This resolve my problem, automaticle add the class and remove the previosuly, one more questions this no requery remove class for remove the previous class or is inherit at the method you use???

Comment: i use removeAttr for remove previous class

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you want, Instead of hard coding the `if` statements just try to add `data` for the elements in the markup and go ahead with this code.

```
var menu = $('.menu-primary li').click(function () {
    menu.not($(this).toggleClass($(this).data("class"))).removeClass();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kLm1fb0v/2/)

Comment: This is another way to do all i want thanks for the response,  im New and if statments resolve all of my problems i try to do in my new projects variants like your code

Comment: You get my upvote for your answer on any account! Although, admittedly, it is not *that* easy to read for a newcomer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$("#my_id").addClass('active');
```

This is what you need?

Comment: No, because the class is not the same, the class i try to add is, one,two,three,four,five etc each class have different style.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **some** vanilla javascript in this instance:

```
var nums = ['zero','one','two','three'];

$('.menu-primary li').click(function(){
    if( nums[parseInt(this.id)].length ){ // verifies class exists
        this.className = nums[parseInt(this.id)]; // completely overwrites class
    }
});
```